# Why is dplyr::slice not accepting my value for its weight_by argument?

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to use dplyr's slice_min and slice_max functions, but it keeps giving me an error whenever I want to weight by another variable in the data frame.

`affordable_zips <- slice_max(count_incomes_zip2, prop = .8, order_by = affordable_zip, weight_by = total_zip)`

In this example, affordable_zip is a length 144 vector of numeric values. So is total_zip. So I don't understand why I'm getting the following error:

> Error in `dplyr::slice_max()`:
> ! `...` must be empty.
> x Problematic argument:
> *weight_by = total_zip<

To give some context, each row in the data frame is a zip code, affordable_zip is a numeric variable representing the number of "affordable" housing units in that zip code, and total_zip is another numeric variable representing the total housing stock in that zip code. The code works if I don't try to weight it by total_zip, by the way, but obviously this means that a decent amount of the results for slice_min will be zip codes with very few units overall (which doesn't interest me).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see `weight_by` in the arguments for `slice_sample` but not `slice_max`. I don't use those functions, but are you certain that `slice_max` is supposed to be *weighted*? (What does a "weighted max" mean?) (BTW, `slice_sample` doesn't support `order_by=` ... but you can always follow with `arrange(affordable_zip)`.)